# React datepicker disable dates after two weeks

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) module in my website. I want to disable the dates after 2 weeks. for example, today date is : 20-02-2019, so i want to disable dates after 5 march 2019.

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you share some piece of code. So, that it becomes easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a date that is 13 days into the future to the `maxDate` prop.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wn069ozjy7))**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date()
  };

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  };

  render() {
    const twoWeeksFromNow = new Date();
    twoWeeksFromNow.setDate(twoWeeksFromNow.getDate() + 13);

    return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        maxDate={twoWeeksFromNow}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: it's working with  react-date picker, if you want to disable today date then use (-1) please of (+13)

Answer (score 0):

You can add maxDate attribute to your datepicker code.

```
   maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 13)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com)** component you are using, already has **includeDates** parameter.

```
() => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
    return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
            includeDates={[new Date(), addDays(new Date(), 1)]}
            placeholderText="This only includes today and tomorrow"
        />
    );
};
```

This above code is for showing only today and tomorrow. If you want to show dates for two weeks, simply add the list of days in array (line 7).

Link for that particular section https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-include-dates